# Existence of full-rank function with given components

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-rank

Assume that $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open and $f_1,...,f_k : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable functions such that $(f_1,...,f_k)$ has rank $k$ everywhere.

Can we find more functions $f_{k+1},...,f_n : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(f_1,...,f_n)$ has rank $n$ everywhere?

When $n$ is even we can take a matrix $A$ with no real eigenvalues; then $f_1$ and $f_2 := A \cdot f_1$ always form a rank-$2$ function. I don't know whether this can be extended to answer the question though.

Comment: Do $f_{k+1},\ldots,f_n$ need to be differentiable as well? If not, the answer is trivially yes.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes. I would prefer for $f_1,...,f_n$ to be $C^{\infty}$ but differentiable once is fine.